# Trying to install private php repository in Docker container

Tags: git, docker, ssh, composer-php

I'm upgrading a package that requires a private package (the code for this package is hosted on bitbucket).
I've created a `docker-compose.yaml` file with the following contents:

```
version: '3'
services:
  composer:
    image: composer:2.3.5
    environment:
      - COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/app/.cache/composer
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa:ro
```

So I just need to run `docker-compose run composer install` to install all required dependencies and it works perfectly with public packages. However, when it tries to install the private package I'm getting this error:

```
  git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).                                                                                                                    
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                       
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                                                                  
  and the repository exists.
```

I'm passing the private key to the container and it even asks for the passphrase when I try to run `composer install` but I keep getting this `Permission denied` error.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Permisson denied (publickey)` tells you that it's using the wrong public key, even though you're supplying the passphrase. Add additional verbose tracing (e.g., set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v`, or run a debug `ssh -vT` in the docker image before trying to clone) to figure out why.

Comment: Also compare with the Composer Docker images [How to use this image](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/composer/README.md#how-to-use-this-image) section in full, there is more suggested than mounting the SSH key (in fact it [exemplifies using the SSH Agent for private repositories](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/composer/README.md#private-repositories--ssh-agent)). Otherwise, same as @torek wrote: Check SSH public key configuration, the error is not from composer but git. And then `composer -vvv` can help trouble-shooting, too.

Comment: Please provide reference where you have taken the information from to mount the SSH private key file to add more context to your question. And can you elaborate a bit more why you did expect it to work? And what is your operating system, the Docker client and server version as well as docker-compose version?